# sencha touch :: list is not scrolling right

Tags: list, sencha-touch

the following code seems to be incomplete or I am doing something wrong?
problem is that the list doesn't scroll right.

```
Ext.ns('simfla.ux.plugins.demo');

Ext.regModel('Contact', {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

simfla.ux.plugins.demo.store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Contact',
    sorters: 'firstName',

    data: [
        {firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
        {firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
        {firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
        {firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
        {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
        {firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
        {firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
        {firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
        {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
        {firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
        {firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
        {firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
        {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
        {firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
        {firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
        {firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
        {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Robinson'}
    ]
})

Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    icon: 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady : function() {
        var app =  new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            dockedItems:[{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'EditableList Plugin',

            }],
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title:'topPanel',
                items:{
                    xtype:'button',
                    cls: 'editChildBtn',
                    text: 'Einstellungen',
                    width: 150,
                    handler: function(){}
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                style: 'background-color: Transparent;',
                id: 'MyList',
                allowDeselect: true,
                clearSelectionOnDeactivate: true,
                //layout: 'fit',
                store: simfla.ux.plugins.demo.store,
                itemTpl: '{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong>',
                grouped: false,
                indexBar: false,
                singleSelect: true,
                }]
            });

    }
});
```

thanx for having a look!

edit: doesn't scroll right means that it is flipping back to initial position when letting loose the grip...

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, what do you mean by doesn't scroll right?

Comment: shure. the list behaves like it is not a list but a normal panel, sliding back when you let loose the finger/mouse.

Comment: I have the same Issue... If you find an solution, could you let me know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that the parent container won't be able to figure out the height the list should have because there are two children, so 'fit' doesn't really have a meaning. If you change the parent's layout from a fit to a vbox, give the 'topPanel' a fixed height and the list a flex of 1 the two children should fill the screen.

```
var app =  new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: {
           type: 'vbox',
           align: 'stretch'
        },
        dockedItems:[{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'EditableList Plugin',

        }],
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title:'topPanel',
            height: 50,
            items:{
                xtype:'button',
                cls: 'editChildBtn',
                text: 'Einstellungen',
                width: 150,
                handler: function(){}
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            flex: 1,
            style: 'background-color: Transparent;',
            id: 'MyList',
            allowDeselect: true,
            clearSelectionOnDeactivate: true,
            //layout: 'fit',
            store: simfla.ux.plugins.demo.store,
            itemTpl: '{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong>',
            grouped: false,
            indexBar: false,
            singleSelect: true,
            }]
        });
```

Comment: thnx - i will try this, soon!

Answer (score 1):

Give `'padding-bottom'` style to panel that surrounds two panels.

In my case '100px' is the best.

```
    Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    icon: 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady : function() {
        var app =  new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            style: 'padding-bottom:100px;',
            dockedItems:[{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'EditableList Plugin',

            }],
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title:'topPanel',
                items:{
                    xtype:'button',
                    cls: 'editChildBtn',
                    text: 'Einstellungen',
                    width: 150,
                    handler: function(){}
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                style: 'background-color: Transparent;',
                id: 'MyList',
                allowDeselect: true,
                clearSelectionOnDeactivate: true,
                //layout: 'fit',
                store: simfla.ux.plugins.demo.store,
                itemTpl: '{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong>',
                grouped: false,
                indexBar: false,
                singleSelect: true,
                }]
            });

    }
});
```